# MinGW - Update GCC version 3.4.5 to version 4.4

Tags: mingw

I've successfully installed MinGW from the directions located [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started) (Automated Install). But, I wanted to get the GCC version updated to 4.4. Do I simply overlay the files in my installation directory (`C:\MinGW\`)? If not, how do I properly install this new version of MinGW/GCC?

If this has been asked before, I'm sorry. I searched, but I was unable to find the answer (either here or on MinGW.org).

**Note**: I'm wanting to install the files at: http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/ under GCC Version 4 called: gcc-full-4.4.0-mingw32-bin-2.tar.lzma

I'm hoping for more feedback. I appreciate Ravadre's response but more information would also be great!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've personally just dropped the new compiler files in, and it works like a charm (I've done it with 4.3.0 to be exact), although I can't guarantee that this is a should-do solution.

I'm talking of course about files that can be downloaded from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/ under *GCC Version 4*.

Comment: Yes, those are the files I'm looking at. Thank you for sharing your experience.

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to unzip those GCC files over an existing MinGW/MSYS install.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to keep the installations completely separate in different directories. This allows me to compile old projects with old versions of the compiler when necessary. At one point I had 2.95, 3.x and 4.4.0 all working happily together, so this is a viable option.