# Why isn't the gcc 4.x.x series compilers installed by MinGW by default?

Tags: c++, gcc, mingw, gcc4, gcc3

Currently, [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org/)'s only installs the 3.x.x series of the gcc compiler by default.  However, it looks like the 4.x.x series of compilers have been out for some time, and as [others have mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151420/mingw-update-gcc-version-3-4-5-to-version-4-4), it seems to work just fine.  Is there any reason why it hasn't moved to the 4.x.x versions yet, and any reason why I shouldn't use the newer versions of gcc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC4's C++ ABI has changed from GCC3, and it includes a lot of new features (like its tree vectorization) that a lot of people still consider "experimental." There are still a few Linux distributions still using GCC3 for that reason.

Comment: The major C++ abi change was like back in 2001.  About 10 years has passed. TEN YEARS!  Why can't you just get along with it?

Comment: When gcc fully supports C99, maybe we can validly complain that people shouldn't still be using an ABI replaced 10 years ago.

Comment: I'm aware of at least 3 ABI changes since GCC-2.95: 3.0, 3.3, and 4.0. I don't know exactly what changed, only that something did. Jerry noted that the exception mechanism was among those changes.

Answer (score 4):

The [TDM GCC/MinGW32 builds](http://www.tdragon.net/recentgcc/) installer includes **gcc 4.4.x** and all the core binary packages required for basic Windows development, including gdb. It's widely used without any unusual problems.

Answer (score 3):

The issue appears to be that they've changed the exception handling mechanism in a way that breaks the ABI. That means you can't (for example) drop in the new compiler and continue to use old object files and/or libraries. You have to re-compile everything from source code to get working results at all.

Comment: GCC support for windows is not as strong, so there are probably lurking bugs, so until they feel it's more stable, they stick with the tried and true.