# Which version of gcc to install with MinGW?

Tags: c, gcc, mingw

If [compiling and linking with MinGW gcc v3 is painfully slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929495/why-is-mingw-very-slow), and [gcc v4 is not the default install option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568949/why-isnt-the-gcc-4-x-x-series-compilers-installed-by-mingw-by-default): What, for a beginner are the advantages/disadvantages of installing one version or another?

Say for example with gcc v4, I want to use [PDCurses](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/pdcurses.htm) or other GNU libraries will I first have to recompile these from source?

I'm only asking here about C and not C++.

Comment: I have needed cygwin for programming an embedded device, and i don't know the gcc version. Which means that for a beginner, it does not matter :)

Comment: afaik the current MinGW installer/updater (ie version 5.1.6) supports GCC4, ie a manual copying of the binaries is no longer necessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using MinGW with GCC4 for some time and didn't encounter any problems, so I'd say go for it. Also, there's no need for recompilation as the C [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) on Windows has been stable for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

The [TDM GCC/MinGW32 builds](http://www.tdragon.net/recentgcc/) installer includes **gcc 4.4.x** and all the core binary packages required for basic Windows development, including gdb. It's widely used without any unusual problems.

Answer (score 0):

One advantage of gcc4 is that you can compile recent QT4.6, as it is compiled with gcc4.
Of course some new additions, like OpenMP need new gcc versions.
However, there are complains about MingW port of gcc4 to be unstable for certain applications.